# Weird behavior when solving a simple physics problem

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code in Mathematica that represents two balls being thrown, one with a velocity v10 (6 in this case) and another ball thrown with a velocity v20 (its just dropped) one second later:

```
v10 = 6    
v20 = 0
a = -9.8
t0 = 0

v1[t_] = Integrate[a, t] + v10
v2[t_] = Integrate[a, t] + v20
x1[t_] = Integrate[v1[t], t] + h
x2[t_] = Integrate[v2[t], t] + h

eq1 = (t /. Solve[0 == x2[t], t]) + 1
eq2 = t /. Solve[0 == x1[t], t]

eq4 = Solve[eq1[[2]] == eq2[[2]]]
```

> {{h -> 0.410596}}

h is the height the balls begin at in order to meet the ground at the same time.  All is good.  But as soon as I plug in a variable, V, for the velocity v10 everything falls apart:

```
v10 = V    
v20 = 0
a = -9.8
t0 = 0

v1[t_] = Integrate[a, t] + v10
v2[t_] = Integrate[a, t] + v20
x1[t_] = Integrate[v1[t], t] + h
x2[t_] = Integrate[v2[t], t] + h

eq1 = (t /. Solve[0 == x2[t], t]) + 1
eq2 = t /. Solve[0 == x1[t], t]

eq4 = Solve[eq1[[2]] == eq2[[2]]]
```

> {h -> 1.61298*10^-61 (5.40298*10^92 - 1.10265*10^92 V + 
>        5.62576*10^90 V^2 - 
>        1. (-2.32443*10^46 + 2.37187*10^45 V) Sqrt[
>         5.40298*10^92 - 1.10265*10^92 V + 5.62576*10^90 V^2])}, {h -> 
>     1.61298*10^-61 (5.40298*10^92 - 1.10265*10^92 V + 
>        5.62576*10^90 V^2 + (-2.32443*10^46 + 2.37187*10^45 V) Sqrt[
>         5.40298*10^92 - 1.10265*10^92 V + 5.62576*10^90 V^2])}

Then if I go further and try to plug 6 back into the equation for V:

```
x[V_] = h /. eq4[[1]]
x[6]
```

> 2.62065*10^31

This is obviously the wrong answer. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I cannot replicate the indicated results. I guess some input is missing. By eyeball I do not see 'V' anywhere, for example.

Comment: You're right, Daniel.  It had a typo.  It should work now.

Comment: Still nope, I think the problem is `Solve[x10 == x2[t], t]`.  Note the undefined variable `x10`.

Comment: I thought I got rid of that variable.  I had two edits - now it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've encountered floating-point roundoff error.  Note the combination of very large and very small numbers in `eq4`.

Let's try something different.  I'll evaluate just your integrals, without the numbers:

```
v1[t_] = Integrate[a, t] + v10
v2[t_] = Integrate[a, t] + v20
x1[t_] = Integrate[v1[t], t] + h
x2[t_] = Integrate[v2[t], t] + h
```

Now we'll just `Solve` for `t` and `h`.

```
FullSimplify@Solve[x1[t] == 0 && x2[t-t0] == 0, {h, t}]
```

> {{h -> -((t0 (a t0 + 2 v10) (a t0 - 2 v20) (a t0 + 2 v10 - 2 v20))/(
>       8 (a t0 + v10 - v20)^2)), 
>     t -> (t0 (a t0 - 2 v20))/(2 (a t0 + v10 - v20))}}

Now let's simply substitute our values:

```
% /. {v10 -> 6, v20 -> 0, a -> -9.8, t0 -> 1}
```

> {{h -> 0.410596, t -> 1.28947}}

I've noticed that Mathematica often has trouble dealing with mixed symbolic/machine-precision expression.  It was your intermediate `Solve` that gave it difficulty.

I almost always evaluate symbolically first.  If your equation has no analytical solution, substitute your numbers as the last step before `Solve`.

Comment: I would also suggest using `DSolve` instead of `Integrate`, it will let you handle more complex cases easily.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I had to use my original equations since your FullSimplify line didn't work for me (I got h->0, t->0), but substituting the numbers at the end worked like a charm.

Comment: @Mardymar Oops, the reason you got {h->0,t->0} was that I forgot the time offset.  Check the `Solve` again now.